# Create a list comprehension with two or more properties

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let's say I have this dictionary and I want a list of names and id.

`d = [{'name': 'testtt', id: 1, 'stuff': 123}, {'name': 'test', id: 2, 'stuff', 123`}]

I could do:

```
items = []

for item in d:
    items.append(d['name'])
    items.append(d['id'])
```

Can it be done in the same list comprehension?

Something like this:

`items = [item['name'], item['id'] for item in d`]

Comment: You can do that yes.... Wouldn't it make more sense to `items` be a list of 2-lists or 2-tuples though to keep the structure? (or is that what you're trying to do - as you'd just need `()` or `[]` around the items to do that)

Comment: it looks wierd, but it has sense because I am using it to create a big array with terms I can then apply some search logic at the frontend that's why I dont need to preserve the structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it using a nested loop to add items from each dict field:

```
items = [x for dct in d for x in (dct['name'], dct['id'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools`:

```
d = [{'name': 'testtt', 'id': 1, 'stuff': 123}, {'name': 'test', 'id': 2, 'stuff':123}]
from itertools import chain
new_d  = list(chain.from_iterable([(i["name"], i["id"]) for i in d]))
```

Output:

```
['testtt', 1, 'test', 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Note you **have to change the id** into string, otherwise it refer0s to the built-in id function. You can do this

```
d = [{'name': 'testtt', 'id': 1, 'stuff': 123}, {'name': 'test', 'id': 2, 'stuff': 123}]

items = map(lambda x: (x['name'], x['id']), d)


>>> items
[('testtt', 1), ('test', 2)]
```